# Wrap Panel with scroll viewer

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using `WrapPanel` for dynamic content display line by line order like windows explorer windows, its working but when the horizontal and vertical `ScrollBar` enabled the `WrapPanel` display the contents are single line. Here we have contents less than 4 it shows perfect otherwise display single line.

Here is my `xaml` code

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,10">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Designs}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,11,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DsnName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" Foreground="#FF878787"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image,FallbackValue={StaticResource Lost},TargetNullValue={StaticResource Lost},Mode=TwoWay}" Stretch="Fill" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,10" Width="174"/>
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,14,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="16"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

How can fix this issue

Comment: If you use `ScrollViewer`, the content will automatically be given as much space as it needs. So, if there's no limit on the width of the `WrapPanel`, there is no need to wrap. If you want wrapping, you have to either disable horizontal scrolling or set a maximum width on the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set height of WrapPanel or disable scrolling